# Converting a rectangular equation to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus, cylindrical-coordinates

If I have an equation like $x^2+y^2+4z^2=10$, would the cylindrical equation then just be $r^2=10-4z^2$? I found this answer, but it just seems like it was too easy to find.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2 + y^2 + 4z^2 = 10$$ represents an ellipsoid centered at the origin in Cartesian coordinates. To express this equation in cylindrical coordinates, you can substitute $x$ and $y$ with their equivalent cylindrical coordinates, $r \cdot \cos(\theta)$ and $r \cdot \sin(\theta)$, respectively. The equation becomes:

$$( r \cdot \cos(\theta))^2 + (r \cdot \sin( \theta))^2 + 4z^2 = 10.$$

Simplifying this equation, we have:

$$r^2 + 4z^2 = 10.$$

[image]